# MediaElement windows phone 8.1 rt

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with mediaElement. Assume I play a video with mediaElement, and my phone locks the screen after 1 minute.
So, after 1 minute, the mediaElement stops playing the video and the phone is on the lock screen. But I want to play the video normally.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `MediaElement` is so by design. There's no playback supported behind the lock screen.
Question isn't clear, but I think you want to prevent the phone from locking itself while video is being played. To do so, you must create a `DisplayRequest` object at global scope and set it to active when you start the playback.

```
if (dispRequest == null) 
{        
    dispRequest = new DisplayRequest();
    dispRequest.RequestActive();

    rootPage.NotifyUser("Display request activated", NotifyType.StatusMessage);        
}
```

Also, make sure to call the `RequestRelease()` once playback is finished.
You can find more details at MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/jj152728.aspx).